# UiSegementedController's segment automatically select in UITableViewCell when scroll the uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have added `UISegmentedController` to `TableViewCell` in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`. 
Following is the code.

```
[cell.segStatus addTarget:self action:@selector(selectedSegmentControl:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell.segStatus setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
cell.segStatus.tag = indexPath.row;
```

I use `UITableViewCell` class for customized class.

I select segment and when I scroll the tableview  some other cell's segmented controller  also automatically select.
Why is it? how can I sort out this ?

Full CellForRowAtIndexPath Method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  @try {
    static NSString *defTableIdentifier = @"DefectRegisterCell";
    DefectRegisterCell *cell = (DefectRegisterCell *)[self.tblDefectList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:defTableIdentifier];

            _defectEntry = [defectObjList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            cell.lblDefectNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _defectEntry.defectNo];

      if ([_defectEntry.defect isEqual:@"None"] || [_defectEntry.defect isEqual:@""] ) {
          cell.lblDefect.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ - Passed", _defectEntry.item,_defectEntry.subItem];
      }
      else{
            cell.lblDefect.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ - %@", _defectEntry.item,_defectEntry.subItem,_defectEntry.defect];
      }
            cell.lblLocation.text = @"Location:";
            cell.lblLocationValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ > %@ > %@ > %@  (%@ - %@)",_defectEntry.building, _defectEntry.area, _defectEntry.location, _defectEntry.room,_defectEntry.orient, _defectEntry.position];

            cell.lblAssignedTo.text = @"Assigned to:";
            cell.lblAssignedToValue.text = _defectEntry.responsibleComp;

            cell.lblDue.text = @"Due:";
            cell.lblDueValue.text = _defectEntry.dueDate;

            cell.lblCapturedBy.text = @"Recorded by:";
            cell.lblCapturedByValue.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",_defectEntry.inspectedId,_defectEntry.inspectedCompId];

            cell.lblDate.text = @"On:";
            cell.lblDateValue.text = _defectEntry.createdDate;
            NSString *attached = @"0" ;
            NSString *fixClaimed = @"0";
            NSString *completed = @"0";
            if ([_defectEntry.attached length] > 0) {
                attached = @"1";
            }
            if ([_defectEntry.fixClaimed isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
                fixClaimed = @"1";
            }

            if ([_common checkDateValidation:_defectEntry.completed]) {
                completed = @"1";
            }

          [cell.segStatus addTarget:self action:@selector(selectedSegmentControl:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
          [cell.segStatus setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
          cell.segStatus.tag = indexPath.row;

            if ([attached isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                cell.imgAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"diAttachments.png"];

            }
            if ([fixClaimed isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                cell.imgDefect.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"diWarning.png"];
                cell.segStatus.hidden = NO;

            } else  if ([completed isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                cell.imgDefect.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"diRight.png"];

                if ([_defectEntry.passed isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
                    cell.segStatus.hidden = YES;
                }
                else{
                    cell.segStatus.hidden = NO;
                }

            } else {
                cell.imgDefect.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"diWrong.png"];
                cell.segStatus.hidden = NO;
            }

            UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            if (indexPath.row % 2) {
                backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            } else {
                backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:242/255.0f green:242/255.0f blue:242/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
            }
            cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;

            //change the selected cell color
            UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = gaSelectedColor;
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
      return cell;
    }
    @catch(NSException *excp)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",excp);
    }
}
```

Comment: add your CellForRowAtIndexPath method full code

Comment: Nope : System is crashed. when I use that code line. :(

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not adding cell programatically. I have already created cell and add a sub class. I have given "DefectRegisterCell" name to that cell. so how NSString *defTableIdentifier ; identify that created cell? So this edited solution also not working.

Comment: I think you are calling `[cell.segStatus addTarget:self action:@selector(selectedSegmentControl:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];` every cell refresh. This will add multiple targets to multiple cells (when a cell is reused). One option is to test if there is already a target before adding - `cell.segStatus.allTargets.count > 0`